# WM6 Contact Sync Google

Tags: c#, synchronization, windows-mobile, google-contacts-api

I am looking to write a contact synchronisation application for windows mobile and google contacts.  I am developing against the Windows Mobile 6 platform for the time being and using the PocketOutlook managed classes and C#.

An initial problem I have come up with whilst doing some research is the fact that the contacts do not have an accessible last updated date! After reading some posts on MS forums one of the suggested approaches is to monitor for contact changes, this does not seem like a good idea on a compact device as there is no OS level ContactUpdated event that i can find and each contact object has an Updated event for each property! Working with this if i had 100 contacts each with 10 properties i would be subscribing to 1000 events (I have many more contacts and there are many more properties!).

There are plenty of synchronisation services for WM6 so there must be a way around this problem, but as of yet I haven't come up with one.

There is a Properties collection exposed on the contact under which you can add custom properties but as the standard contact editor in windows mobile will not populate this when editing a contact I can't see how I could use it to my advantage.

Has anybody faced this issue before and if so how was this dealt with?

The Google objects do have an updated date and I will know the date of the last sync so downloads are fine.

Thanks in advance

OneShot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up on this, I got as far as being able to push everything up to google contacts but then had to resort to comparing all the properties of each contact at each sync.